# Creating java project with sbt

Tags: java, sbt

I am new to sbt and I am trying to create a java project with it from command line. And I followed the conventions for directory structure :

```
src>
  main>
    java>
        <--java file-->
```

And I wrote simple build.sbt file which has the following lines

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.3"
name :="New-Folder"
version := "1.0"
```

In cmd, from New-Folder directory, I executed sbt and in the end it's showing 'Couldn't create directory C:/xxx/New-Folder/project'. I tried placing build.sbt inside New-Folder and src folders and running sbt but to no success.

Can somebody please tell me what is the correct place to keep this build.sbt file in the directory structure and some pointers as to the correct way to build java project with sbt.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Read sbt documentation carefully: [Directory structure](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Directories.html).

If your project is in `C:/xxx/New-Folder/`,

- you should have `build.sbt` in the root of the project, i.e. `C:/xxx/New-Folder/build.sbt`
- same about `src/`, it should be `C:/xxx/New-Folder/src/main/java/...`

If sbt still says `Couldn't create directory ...`, probably there is some problem with write permissions.